# Should "quartus" and "quartus-ii" be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Both tags [quartus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus) and [quartus-ii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) actually refer to the same piece of software provided by Altera. The tag wiki on [quartus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus) reads (excerpt):

> Quartus is a software product developed by Altera which assists in the design of FPGA and CPLD

The name Quartus II is used in the longer tag description and the software was also never named Quartus only. The predecessor was MAX+PLUS II.

The tag wiki on [quartus-ii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) starts with:

> Quartus II is a software tool produced by Altera for analysis and synthesis of HDL designs, [...]

Both tags have been created back in 2014, whereby [quartus-ii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) has been created 4 month earlier. This tag has also more associated questions with it (121 vs. 49) and more followers (27 vs. 13). 
Thus up to here, [quartus-ii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) seems to be the more appropriate tag and [quartus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus) should be a synonym of [quartus-ii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii).

**But**, with the release of version 15.0 in November 2015, Altera renamed this software suite to Quartus Prime. It is a direct successor of Quartus II 14.1. Many backend tools are still the same, so that reported error messages (regarding [vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) and [verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verilog) code) are still the same. Now, keeping the tag [quartus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus), refering to both Quartus II and Quartus Prime, seems to be more appropriate.

Keeping both tags [quartus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus) and [quartus-ii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) or introducing a new "quartus-prime" makes no sense at the moment because it does not differentiate anything.

So which tag should be kept to cover both Quartus II and Quartus Prime?
(Of course, the other tag should be made a synonym.)

Should I suggest the same (improved) tag wiki text for both tags, so that, it is more clearly visible that both tags refer to the same software?

Comment: [quartus] is plenty good enough, unlikely that anybody is going to ask about World Healing Day.  Just propose synonyms so it all gets mapped to one tag.

Comment: I have no rights to up/down vote synonyms, because it seems that I answered only Xilinx questions and no Altera questions ... **But** I would like to see only a [tag:quartus] tag + [tag:quartus-ii] as a synonym.

Comment: @Paebbels I was about to suggest the same thing. I don't have the privilege to do anything about it, either.

Answer (score 2):

[quartus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus) seems good enough to me, just as it did to all of the commenters here.

...So it is now done. **[quartus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus) is the master tag.** I merged [quartus-ii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) into it, and created a synonym. I also did a manual "merge" of the tag wikis, but I don't know anything about this software, so someone knowledgeable might want to check up on it and make sure it says what we want it to say.

It appears that the name is now "Quartus Prime", but I didn't see a [quartus-prime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus-prime) tag, so I didn't bother creating that synonym. Let me know if it is needed.

Comment: A Quartus Prime tag is not required. The name change is just marketing.