# Sympathy for a tag synonym request required

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I was going to suggest that the [quartus-ii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) tag be removed and replaced with as a synonym for [quartus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartus). But, it turns out that that had already been suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321303/should-quartus-and-quartus-ii-be-synonyms).

But nothing happened. Three people (including me, just now) voted and commented and, errr... that's it. Nothing happened, because it seems like few people that respond to questions with these tags has the reputation on these tags to do anything about it. Yet I see [the same action being requested on another pair of tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345073/should-these-two-tags-be-combined-bll-and-business-logic-layer) and, bish-bosh, job done.

How can one progress this?

Comment: Offer a bount.. damn.  Seriously, should be able to mod flag to get it featured.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, what do you mean "mod flag to get it featured"?

Comment: flag the question in need of moderator intervention and then in the dialogue box, tell them you would like it featured to draw more attention since the post has gone no where.

Comment: See [How to gather support for tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312430/how-to-gather-support-for-tag-synonyms), funnily, that question itself didn't gather attention.

Comment: Good luck. Once I asked readers in a question with the `d3.js-v4` tag (which makes no sense) to [vote it as a synonym of d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/d3.js/synonyms)... at that time we needed just one more vote. What happened? Someone went there and **voted down**! Luckily it is 3 votes up again, but probably it will stay like that forever...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I've just looked at the "top users" for the [quartus] tag. There are only 4 with enough reputation to do anything. Ever. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/quartus/topusers

Comment: @MatthewTaylor On top of that, I just saw that only 3 of them are currently "active"... so, your group had a loss of 25%!

Comment: @BhargavRao I know the diamond after your name means that you have more powers (and responsibilities, I'm sure). Do you have the power to do anything about this?

Comment: @Matthew, Nope, I don't have enough power to motivate people to vote on synonyms. But I do have the power to unilaterally create synonyms. I usually check the [meta-tag:synonym-requests] page and create synonyms whenever the post has has a score of more than 10 and there are no opposing answers.

Comment: @BhargavRao Should this be taken as a rule moderators have, or just your personal action whenever you can?

Comment: @Llopis There's no rule about any of these. This is what I've been doing (just a small bit to help). If the mods and CMs come up with a new rule, then I'd be abiding by that. :)

Comment: @VadimKotov I refer to that question in mine, but 4 months after asking my question and 16 months after asking that one suddenly bang! somebody called Cody Gray has done what was requested. (It's only a duplicate because the first question has finally been answered.)

Answer (score 14):

The best way to make progress on a tag synonym request is probably to draw attention to all the feature requests (around here somewhere...) asking to:

- Make [suggested synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested) easier to discover and to generally improve that UI.

  I bet most users don't even know about the above page.
  One suggestion was to add it to [the review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review).
- Make it easier (change / lower the requirements) to propose and vote on synonyms.

  It seems silly that I can't even vote on suggested synonyms for most tags when I can do so many other things on this site, and plenty single-handedly.

Or convince moderators to take over the job of creating synonyms.

Few users see proposed synonyms and much fewer still actually meet the criteria to suggested or vote on said synonyms, so a lot of synonym requests probably just come to Meta to be forgotten about.

Comment: Just another example: [queryover](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/queryover/synonyms). It has even the exact same description as its proposed synonym, [nhibernate-queryover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-queryover). Yet I am still one point off being able to vote for it, and no-one has (was able to?) vote for it.

Comment: *Or convince moderators to take over the job of creating synonyms* ... well, many moderators are already doing this. I go through the list of proposals on meta and synonymize those that have received at least 10 upvotes.

Comment: I didn't know of that list. Just went there and voted. You said there was a feature request to add it to the review page. Could you link that?

Comment: @BhargavRao The trouble is with making the tag page more visible is that you need a score of 5 on the tag to suggest a synonym. There are only 4 users ever with a score of 5 on this tag and I'm not one of them - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/quartus/topusers

Answer (score 2):

The question's title isn't punny.

If you make a tag request, and your title isn't punny, you're gonna have a bad time.

Bump the question by making the title punny.

Comment: I first read "punny" as "puny". Puny? What are you talking about? Oh, punny. A punintentional misunderstanding.